# 'microtype.sty' no found even after installing it

Tags: latex

Hi as i'm trying to use latex i get this error 
! LaTeX Error: File `microtype.sty' not found.
[latex error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aldjx.png)
I tried to install it with admin autorisation on miktex and i refresh FNDB but still getting th same error. My microtype.sty is in this folder
'C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\microtype'
PS: those are my roots on miktex
[miktex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l1Nh.png) 
Could you please help me to solve this issue.